# Email when VM is running for more than x hours

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want create an email alert when my GCP instances are running for than x hours .I am using cronjob for the same but I also want the user name of person who started it to shut down the vm

Comment: You will need to parse the Cloud Logging logs to know who/what started an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to know to the name of the person who started the VM on Cloud Logging, as you can see on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/audit-logging).

Besides, I would like to suggest you to install the [Cloud Monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/installation) on the VM, so you will be able to configure the alerts.